# Filtro dinamico con consultas LinQ

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework-6

Estoy armando un filtro dinamico para filtrar (valga la redundancia) un menu para un restaurante, uso un metodo anonimo (apoyandome en un post del usuario gbianchi) para ir armando el predicado (usando los parametros opcionales), pero me da un problema: solo ejecuta el primer predicado que ingresa y me ignora el resto (independientemente de cual sea), alguno sabe por que razon me puede estar haciendo esto?. Uso enum para determinar tipos de filtrados y el estado que tiene que tener en la BBDD para tomar el registro.

Codigo:

```
public enum ETipoListado
{
    Todo, ArticulosActivos = 1, ArticulosInactivos = 2, Filtro
}

#region ArmarPredicado
Func<Articulo, bool> Predicado = null;

/// <summary>
///  Arma un predicado (filtro)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="NuevoPredicado">Predicado que se arma con cada entrada al metodo.</param>
/// <param name="TipoDeCondicional">Indica si concatena con "&&" o "||"</param>
void ArmarPredicado(Func<Articulo, bool> NuevoPredicado, bool TipoDeCondicional)
{
    // Si el preficado a armar es null, asignarle el primer filtro y volver
    if (Predicado == null)
    {
        Predicado = NuevoPredicado;
        return;
    }

    // Guardar el predicado armado hasta ahora (viejo)
    var ViejoPredicado = Predicado;

    // El nuevo predicado sera la union del predicado viejo (que mantiene todos los predicados agregados) y el nuevo
    // (predicado a agregar)
    if (TipoDeCondicional)
    {
        NuevoPredicado = Identificador => ViejoPredicado(Identificador) && NuevoPredicado(Identificador);
    }
    else
    {
        NuevoPredicado = Identificador => ViejoPredicado(Identificador) || NuevoPredicado(Identificador);
    }
}
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Busca todos los datos del registro en cuestion para ser mostrados.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_TipoDeFiltro">Especifica el tipo de listado que se va a realizar.</param>
/// <param name="_InformacionDelError">Devuelve una cadena de texto con informacion para el usuario en caso de que el
/// metodo devuelva null (debido a que ocurrio un error).</param>
/// <param name="_EstadoArticuloBuscar">Parametro opcional que se establece si se va a aplicar el filtro sobre los articulos 
/// activos o inactivos.</param>
/// <param name="_TextoFilto">Parametro opcional que se establece para hacer un filtrado por nombre.</param>
/// /// <param name="_CategoriaFiltro">Parametro opcional que se establece para hacer un filtrado por categoria.</param>
public List<Articulo> LeerListado(ETipoListado _TipoDeFiltro, ref string _InformacionDelError, ETipoListado _EstadoArticuloBuscar = ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos, string _TextoFilto = "", int _CategoriaFiltro = 0)
{
    using (BDRestauranteEntities BBDD = new BDRestauranteEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            switch (_TipoDeFiltro)
            {
                case ETipoListado.Todo: return BBDD.Articulo.Include("CategoriaArticulo").ToList();
                case ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos: return BBDD.Articulo.Include("CategoriaArticulo").Where(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == 1).ToList();
                case ETipoListado.ArticulosInactivos: return BBDD.Articulo.Include("CategoriaArticulo").Where(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == 2).ToList();
                case ETipoListado.Filtro:
                    {
                        // En este caso armo un predicado por defecto (o todos los articulos activos o todos los inactivos)
                        if ((int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos)
                        {
                            ArmarPredicado(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == (int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar, true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ArmarPredicado(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == (int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar, true);
                        }

                        // Al predicado por defecto le agrego que me incluya las categorias que esten activas (y me
                        // ignore de esta forma los articulos activos con categoria inactiva). si no entrra por true,
                        // le digo que me agregue los aticulos que sean activos pero su categoria es inactiva. 
                        if ((int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos)
                        {
                            ArmarPredicado(Identificador => Identificador.CategoriaArticulo.ID_EstadoCategoriaArticulo == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos, true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ArmarPredicado(Identificador => Identificador.CategoriaArticulo.ID_EstadoCategoriaArticulo == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosInactivos, false);
                        }

                        // Agregar predicado de filtro por texto si hay
                        if (_TextoFilto != "")
                        {
                            ArmarPredicado(Identificador => Identificador.Nombre.StartsWith(_TextoFilto), true);
                        }

                        // Agregar predicado de filtro por categoria si hay
                        if (_CategoriaFiltro != 0)
                        {
                            ArmarPredicado(Identificador => Identificador.CategoriaArticulo.ID_EstadoCategoriaArticulo == _CategoriaFiltro, true);
                        }

                        //if (Predicado == null)
                        //{
                        //    return BBDD.Articulo.Include("CategoriaArticulo").Where(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == (int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar && Identificador.ID_CategoriaArticulo == _CategoriaFiltro).ToList();
                        //}

                        // Retornar el predicado
                        return BBDD.Articulo.Include("CategoriaArticulo").Where(Predicado).ToList();
                    } 
                default: return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Error)
        {
            _InformacionDelError = $"Ocurrio un error inesperado al intentar listar los datos: {Error.Message}";
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Etiquetas

Comment: conoces predicateBuilder? es una librería que hace lo que tu deseas. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde mi expriencia si vas a concatenar diferentes filtros tienes dos opciones

- defines algo estilo fluent
- envias una lista de `Func<>`

  creo que la opcion de la lista es lo mas simples, eso de definir si es nuevo o viejo el predicado se arma una espagueti de codigo

  ```
  public List<Articulo> LeerListado(ETipoListado _TipoDeFiltro, ref string _InformacionDelError, ETipoListado _EstadoArticuloBuscar = ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos, string _TextoFilto = "", int _CategoriaFiltro = 0)
  {
      using (BDRestauranteEntities BBDD = new BDRestauranteEntities())
      {
          try
          {
              var query = BBDD.Articulo.Include("CategoriaArticulo");

              switch (_TipoDeFiltro)
              {
                  case ETipoListado.Todo: 
                      return query.ToList();
                  case ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos: 
                      return query.Where(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == 1).ToList();
                  case ETipoListado.ArticulosInactivos: 
                      return query.Where(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == 2).ToList();
                  case ETipoListado.Filtro:
                      {
                          List<Func<Articulo, bool>> filtros = new List<Func<Articulo, bool>>();

                          // En este caso armo un predicado por defecto (o todos los articulos activos o todos los inactivos)
                          if ((int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos)
                          {
                              filtros.Add(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == (int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              filtros.Add(Identificador => Identificador.ID_EstadoArticulo == (int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar);
                          }

                          if ((int)_EstadoArticuloBuscar == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos)
                          {
                              filtros.Add(Identificador => Identificador.CategoriaArticulo.ID_EstadoCategoriaArticulo == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosActivos);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              filtros.Add(Identificador => Identificador.CategoriaArticulo.ID_EstadoCategoriaArticulo == (int)ETipoListado.ArticulosInactivos);
                          }

                          // Agregar predicado de filtro por texto si hay
                          if (_TextoFilto != "")
                          {
                              filtros.Add(Identificador => Identificador.Nombre.StartsWith(_TextoFilto));
                          }

                          // Agregar predicado de filtro por categoria si hay
                          if (_CategoriaFiltro != 0)
                          {
                              filtros.Add(Identificador => Identificador.CategoriaArticulo.ID_EstadoCategoriaArticulo == _CategoriaFiltro);
                          }

                          foreach(var filtro in filtros){
                              query = query.Where(filtro);
                          }

                          return query.ToList();
                      } 
                  default: return null;
              }
          }
          catch (Exception Error)
          {
              _InformacionDelError = $"Ocurrio un error inesperado al intentar listar los datos: {Error.Message}";
              return null;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

como veras se crea una `List<Func<Articulo, bool>>` donde vas poniendo todos los filtros que quieres aplicar, al final los iteras y los agregas a que query

Comment: habria que validarlo, pero creo que el tema pasa porque el where al usarse con un Func retorna un IEnumerable, pero si se usa con un Expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet/2876655 fijate lo que explica Jacob

Comment: sino prueba de usar `Expression<Func<Articulo, bool>>`